# ashx handler called only once from ascx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx, ascx

In .ascx page i have image button as follows:

```
"<asp:Image ID="imgPhotos" runat="server" Width="102" Height="82"/>"
```

In its code behind, I have:

```
this.imgPhotos.ImageUrl = "~/lib/services/GetSpaceImage.ashx";
```

In GetSpaceImage.ashx, i am dynamically generating images. But the problem is, for the first time it works good. But, second time and so on it never generate the new images. Debugger hits hanlder only for the first time(when the application loads). I have tried using:
 "context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);"

at the beginning of the ProcessRequest. But this also did not help. Am i missing anything? Please advice

Comment: What requests do you see in Firebug or Fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser cached this request, add unique param to every ashx url, something like this :

```
this.imgPhotos.ImageUrl = "~/lib/services/GetSpaceImage.ashx?param=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
```

Comment: no need to thanks, if answer is good you should accept it, see FAQ :http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask